# Java 8 lambda expression is present

Tags: java, lambda

First I need to check if data is present in list then get else set default or empty value on a Java 8 stream.

Currently I am using below code without `isPresent` but I dont know how to use isPresent in java8.

I am trying something below which is not perfect:

```
String isScheme = (this.mapProgramApproaches.stream().findFirst().isPresent())? this.mapProgramApproaches.stream().findFirst().get().getIsScheme().toString() : "0";
```

Where as `mapProgramApproaches` this is set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `isPresent()` (it makes no sense to run the `Stream` pipeline twice).

You can use `map` to map the value of the `Optional` to the required `String`, and then
use `orElse()` to return a default value when the `Optional` value is not present:

```
String isScheme = this.mapProgramApproaches.stream()
                                           .findFirst()
                                           .map(o->o.getIsScheme().toString())
                                           .orElse("0");
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
String isScheme = this.mapProgramApproaches.stream()
        .findFirst()
        .map(p -> p.getIsScheme().toString())
        .orElse("0");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about context in which you are doing this, but I suppose that you would like to check whether some object is scheme and then do something with that. In that case I would suggest implement it like this:

```
List<String> mapProgramApproaches = new ArrayList<>();
mapProgramApproaches.stream()
                .filter(this::isScheme)
                .findFirst()
                .ifPresent(this::doYourCode)
                .orElse(defaultValue);
```

It will make your code cleaner. And will help to avoid additional conditionals!